# Remove duplicate fields from a temp table that has no primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I need to remove duplicate fields from a temp table where the fields in question are not exactly identical.

For example, I have the following data:

```
First  Last     DOB
John   Johnson  10.01.02
Steve  Stephens 23.03.02
John   Johnson  2.02.99
Dave   Davies   3.03.03
```

Here, there are two John Johnson's.  I only want to have one John Johnson - I don't care which one.  So the resulting table will look something like:

```
First  Last     DOB
John   Johnson  10.01.02
Steve  Stephens 23.03.02
Dave   Davies   3.03.03
```

I'm using TSQL, but I would prefer to use SQL that is non-proprietary.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm late to the party, but here is a database agnostic solution:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT [First], [Last], MAX(DOB) MaxDob
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY [First], [Last]) B
    ON A.[First] = B.[First] 
    AND A.[Last] = B.[Last]
    AND A.DOB = B.MaxDob
```

[**And here is a sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75c78/2) with a demo for it. (Thanks @JW for the schema of the fiddle)

Answer (score 7):

Sql Server supports `Common Table Expression` and `Window Functions`. With the use of `ROW_NUMBER()` which supplies rank number for every group, you can filter out records which rank is greater than one (*this are duplicates one*)

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  [First], [Last], DOB,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [First], [Last] ORDER BY DOB) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
DELETE FROM records WHERE rn > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0c74/2)
- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY First, Last ORDER BY First,  Last)
   FROM TempTable
)
DELETE CTE 
WHERE RN > 1;
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3ebe/4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER()` to accomplish this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
       First, 
       Last, 
       DOB,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY First, Last ORDER BY DOB) RN
    FROM  
       Table1
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa3b2/1)